# How to update .txt file list after deleting an item in list box

Tags: python, list, tkinter, listbox

I'm new to Python and TKinter.

I can't figure out how to code this one.

Let's say my .txt file consists of 3 names:

`["Bob", "Mark", "John"]`

After deleting `"Mark"` from the list that is displayed in a list box (via `.curselection()` and `listbox.delete(selected_name)`). I want the list from the .txt file to update as:

`["Bob", "John"]`

How do I code this?

This was my attempt:

```
selected_name = name_list.curselection()
name_list.delete(selected_name)

with open("name_list.txt", 'w') as f:
    f.close()
    f.write(name_list.get())
```

It returns a list box index error since I don't know how to get list box items.

Apologies if my explanation is all around the place.

Comment: You forgot to post your attempt to solve this problem.

Comment: Please refer to this guide on how to provide a [mre], and read about [ask]. Remember, we can't help you if we don't know what you've already tried.

Comment: You appear to be trying to write to a file that you've just closed

Comment: How are the names saved in the file? One name per line?

Comment: @acw1668 According to the question they're stored as *["Bob", "Mark", "John"]*

Comment: @DarkKnight If you look into the code in [pastecode.io](https://pastecode.io/s/7gz2r880) posted in OP comment to your answer, they are not.

Comment: @acw1668 Due to potential issues with external hyperlinks I refuse to open such things. Therefore the basis of my answer is limited to what we can all see in text in the original question. This is a matter for OP to clarify

Comment: @DarkKnight That is why I ask OP how the names are saved in the file.

Answer (score 1):

The file contents represent valid JSON.

You will need to open the file for reading and writing. Load the file contents so they're accessible as a Python list. Remove the name from the list. Rewrite the file.

```
import json
import os

def remove_name(filename, name):
    with open(filename, 'r+') as data:
        try:
            lst = json.load(data)
            lst.remove(name)
            data.seek(0, os.SEEK_SET)
            json.dump(lst, data)
            data.truncate()
        except ValueError:
            pass

remove_name('name_list.txt', 'Mark')
```

EDIT:

It seems that the original question is misleading in terms of the way the names are stored in the file. They are, in fact, stored line by line. Therefore:

```
import os

def remove_name(filename, name):
    with open(filename, 'r+') as data:
        names = data.readlines()
        data.seek(0, os.SEEK_SET)
        for _name in names:
            if _name.rstrip() != name:
                data.write(_name)
        data.truncate()
```

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the input. Although I'm not yet familiar with JSON, is there a way to do it without importing libs? I was hoping to be able to edit it quickly just by using the txt file. I've linked a more in-depth code of me attempting to solve my problem but is still open for changes. I can technically remove the selected name to delete but upon reopening the program, the items inside the list box now looks like this: ("Alice\n",) Here's my code so far: https://pastecode.io/s/7gz2r880

Comment: Your data represents valid JSON. If you want to write your own parser feel free. The *json* module is part of your Python installation - i.e., it's not a discrete installation. It's there to make your life easier and your code more robust. So, to answer your question... Yes - you could do it without any imports but it would be a very bad idea

Comment: Good to know. Thanks again. I appreciate the schooling. I learned something new today.